# NSDateFormatter - SetDateFormat

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a text field where the user can insert the date and the time in this format:
MMDDHHMM (11230530) and I want the label to be set as 23 november at 0530 am.
I tried:

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [date text]];

  // Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMdd hh:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:data];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);

// Convert date object to desired output format
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"???????????"];// I don't know how to change the format ;-)
data = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]; 
NSLog(@"%@", data);
[dateFormatter release];
```

but I'm getting null from data. any clue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this code,

```
NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"11230530"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMddHHmm"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
[dateFormatter release];

dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM' at 'hhmm a"];
NSString *stringFromDate=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
//Use this text to display in that textfield
[dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: @KingofBliss I've used this  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM' at  'hhmm a"]; and it also works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in this way

```
NSDate *data = [NSDate stringWithFormat:@"%@", [date text]];];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMdd hh:mm"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:data];
NSLog(@"%@", dateFromString);
```

Hopes it will help.